# Datafactory : write get medata activity structure output to datalake

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to write Generate Metadata to a file in datalake using copy file activity. But getting datatype issue when mapping structure filed to output schema

activity('Generate Metadata').output.structure

error:

Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'value' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object must implement IConvertible.,Source=mscorlib

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, it needs String type. So you should cast your activity('Generate Metadata').output.structure to String. Use this expression to have a try: `@string(activity('Generate Metadata').output.structure)`.